# Adding multiple rows still works in Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Adding multiple rows still works In Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

```
INSERT INTO mahpl (Emp_id, num, roll_no) 
VALUES (98, 14, 24), (88, 45, 46);
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

But when I am trying this same with this query it works just fine

```
INSERT INTO mahpl (Emp_id, num, roll_no) 
VALUES (98, 14, 24);
```

Can someone help me out with this? I need to add multiple rows using a single query

Version detail:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 5.0 6.0
```

Comment: This is your Management Studio version details etc do a `SELECT @@VERSION` to see what version your SQL Server is on. Also check the compatibality mode of your database , it should be set to 100 or later.

Comment: Oddly, you have a comma after your second query, which would actually give you the Incorrect Syntax message you are talking about. Can you paste exactly what you have in your SSMS window?

Comment: I Had Posted Here As It Is In The Question And If You Need More Info In Answering My Question Than Let Me Know ....

Comment: @vivek You were asked @@version and compatibility level, which you have not provided

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86) 
 Feb  9 2007 22:47:07 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output from `SELECT @@VERSION`

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86) 
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

clearly shows you - you might have **SQL Server Management Studio 2012** but you're running against a SQL Server **2005**  database engine.

The SSMS version is irrelevant in this case; what matters is what **database engine** version you're running against. And SQL Server 2005 does **NOT** support multiple `VALUES` tuples. You need to be running against SQL Server **2008** or newer....